# Winston not displaying error details

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I am using `winston` for logging and most of the time it works well, but when there is an exception, it just does not print any details.

Here is my code for configuring `winston`:

```
// Create logger
const logger = winston.createLogger()

// Create timestamp format
const tsFormat = () => (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString()

// Attach transports based on app mode
if (process.env.APP_MODE === 'production') {
  // Log to file
  logger.add(new (winston.transports.DailyRotateFile)({
    filename: path.join(__dirname, '../logs/errors-%DATE%.log'),
    datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH',
    zippedArchive: true,
    format: winston.format.json(),
    handleExceptions: true
  }))
} else {
  // Log to the console
  logger.add(new (winston.transports.Console)({
    timestamp: tsFormat,
    colorize: true,
    handleExceptions: true
  }))
}

module.exports = logger
```

I am also using `Express` and in my error handling middleware, I have this code:

```
const logger = require('../config/winston')
function (err, req, res, next) {
    console.log(err)
    logger.error(err)
    res.status(500).send({ error: 'Please try again later.' })
}
```

The problem is that when an error occurs all `winston` logs is:

> {"level":"error"}

While the good old `console.log()` displays:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined
    at router.post (/Users/balazsvincze/Desktop/testapi/app/routes/upload.js:16:33)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/de/Desktop/testapi/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/balazsvincze/Desktop/testapi/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/Users/balazsvincze/Desktop/testapi/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:53:37)
    at runCallback (timers.js:814:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:745:5)
```

How do I get `winston` to log something like this including the stack trace?

Many thanks!

**EDIT:** If I change the line logger.error(err) to logger.error(err.message), at least I get this:

> {"message":"Cannot read property 'filename' of
>   undefined","level":"error"}

Still very far off from what I am after.

Comment: I can't believe this question isn't more popular. This is on of the first things I need to do when setting up a SERN app

Answer (score 23):

I think what you're missing is `format.errors({ stack: true })` in `winston.createLogger`.

```js
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'debug',
  format: format.combine(
    format.errors({ stack: true }),
    print,
  ),
  transports: [new transports.Console()],
});
```

See [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1338#issuecomment-482784056) for more information.

The reason this is happening is because the interesting `Error` object properties, like `.stack`, are non-enumerable. Some functions check if the their parameters are `Error` instances, like `console.error`, and other functions ignore all non-enumerable properties, like `winston.<log-level>` and `JSON.stringify`.

```js
> console.error(new Error('foo'))
Error: foo
    at repl:1:15
    at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:124:20)
    ...(abbr)

> JSON.stringify(new Error('foo'))
'{}'
```

All that said, it's horrible usability to have an error logger essentially ignore errors... I just lost too much time to this.

Comment: What's our main reason to use logger like Winston? To see errors, as detail as possible. It's a shame that it doesn't work as `console.log` to print full detail of error objects by default.

Comment: Make sure you put `format.errors({ stack: true })` on top of formats if you use `winston.format.combine()`

Answer (score 7):

A quick and dirty way would be to log `err.stack`:

```
logger.error(err.stack);
```

A more elaborate method would be to implement a [custom format](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#formats) specifically for `Error` instances. There's some example code on how to implement that in [this Github issue](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1338#issuecomment-393238865).

Answer (score 7):

Using format.

```
const { combine, timestamp, label, printf } = winston.format;
const myFormat = printf(info => {
    if(info instanceof Error) {
        return `${info.timestamp} [${info.label}] ${info.level}: ${info.message} ${info.stack}`;
    }
    return `${info.timestamp} [${info.label}] ${info.level}: ${info.message}`;
});
winston.createLogger({
    level: "info",
    format: combine(
        winston.format.splat(),
        label({ label: filename}),
        timestamp(),
        myFormat,
    ),
    transports: [
    //
    // - Write to all logs with level `info` and below to `combined.log`
    // - Write all logs error (and below) to `error.log`.
    //
        new winston.transports.File({ filename: path.join(os.tmpdir(), "test", "test.log"), level: "info" }),
    ],
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using nodejs and having trouble with the rejection handlers, I wrote a little module that you can use for reference.

You have to make sure that when you perform the Array De-structuring for format, that you include 'errors'.

```js
const { combine, timestamp, json, errors } = format;
```

Winston documentation states

> The errors format allows you to pass in an instance of a JavaScript Error directly to the logger. It allows you to specify whether not to include the stack-trace.

```js
const errorsFormat = errors({ stack: true })
```

The complete code below is for reference. It is a module that I am using to log some information to a file and some to a mysql database.

```js
require('dotenv').config();
const {createLogger, transports, format} = require('winston');
const { combine, timestamp, json, errors } = format;
const winstonMysql = require('winston-mysql');
const logform  = require('logform');


const errorsFormat = errors({ stack: true })


const options_default = {
    host: 'localhost',
    user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
    password: process.env.MYSQL_LOGIN,
    database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
    table: 'sys_logs_default'
};

const logger = createLogger({
    level: 'info',
    format: format.json(),
    defaultMeta: { service: 'user-service' },
    transports: [
        new transports.Console({
            format: combine(timestamp(), json(), errorsFormat)
        }),
        // or use: options_custom / options_json
        new winstonMysql(options_default),
    ],
    exceptionHandlers: [
    new transports.File({ filename: 'exception.log' }),
  ],
  rejectionHandlers: [
    new transports.File({ filename: 'rejections.log' }),
  ],
});



module.exports = logger;
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue earlier, and I know it's a little but for people who are still looking for a solution can use `utils-deep-clone` package. Just addded a layer above Winston to handle error objects.

```
const winston = require('winston')
const { toJSON } = require('utils-deep-clone')

const winstonLogger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.Console)()
  ]
})

const log = (message, payload) => {
  try {
    payload = toJSON(payload)
    return winstonLogger.log('info', message, payload)
  } catch(error) {
    console.error('some error occured while consoling')
  }
}

const testObj = {
  error: new Error('It should work')
}

log('Testing few bugs', testObj)
```

The output will be:

```
info: Testing few bugs message=It should work, stack=Error: It should work
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/atishay/Desktop/utils-error-deep-log/logger.js:20:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```