# How can I save my message errors in a log file? it writes the success message when it should write the error one

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

I need to create a .log file, which each time I run my code, saves me information, shows me if it ran successfully or if it had an error.
I made a code so that each time the code runs correctly it does so and it works fine, the problem I'm having now is that, if I have an error and it doesn't run, it shows me the success message in the same way, when it should show the Error message.

Here's my code:

```
// inserts data to a DB
function insertOffice(index) {
    ...
}

// Loops the function in order to make an insert each 0.5 seconds
function myLoop() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        let response = insertOffice(i);
        console.log('Running...');
        i++;
        if (i < offices.length) {
            myLoop();
        }
    }, 500)
}

// Runs the looper.
try {
    myLoop();
    logger.info('Success');
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    logger.error(new Error(error));
}
```

here's my Winston config:

```
import *  as  winston from 'winston';
import { format, createLogger, transports } from "winston";
const { timestamp, combine, printf } = format;

const logFormat = printf(({ message, timestamp, stack }) => {
    return `${timestamp} : ${stack || message}`;
});

export const logger = createLogger({
    format: combine(
        format.colorize(),
        timestamp({ format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss' }),
        format.errors({ stack: true }),
        logFormat
    ),
    'transports': [
        new winston.transports.File({
            filename: 'logs/example.log'
        })
    ]
});
```

As you can see, the plan is to run the function inside a try catch, so when it fails (goes to the catch) it shows me the `logger.error(new Error(error));` but it seems it is not entering the catch.

When I do an insert and everything works fine, in my `example.log` file, it should be written:

```
2022-02-03 08:25:18 : Success
```

And it does, but when I write an error in my code on purpose, to check if it works also for the message error, it doesn't, it still writes the succes message.

I already searched some questions here, like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630896/winston-not-displaying-error-details) for example, but it doesn't seems to me, to fit in my error.

It should be written in my `example.log` the timestamp and the message error, but it doesn't.

Is it the right way to write the message error?

EDIT:
I searched and watched this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41431605/handle-error-from-settimeout) that may because maybe, the settimeout was causing the error, but I'm still getting the same result, the Success message is written and not the error one.

I noticed it can be an issue with the try catch, but I can't find a solution to that.

EDIT: I added what Mojtaba told me to, looking this way:

```
function myLoop() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        try {
            let response = insertOffice(i);
            i++;
            if (i < offices.length) {
                myLoop();
            }
            //throw Error('unexpected Error');
            console.log('success');
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('failed');
        }
    }, 500)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to run this code..

```js
function myLoop() {
    setTimeout(function () {
       throw Error('unexpected Error')
    }, 500)
}

// Runs the looper.
try {
    myLoop();
    console.log('success')
} catch (error) {
    console.log('does it reach here??');
}
```

In this example: you see when an error occured in the `setTimeout()`, it doesn't catch by you'r try and catch statement.

You maybe try to use below code structure:

```js
function myLoop() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    try {
      throw Error('unexpected Error')
      console.log('success')
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('does it reach here??');
    }

  }, 500)
}

// Runs the looper.

myLoop();
```

if you have problem with this example , try to figure out if you'r code throw any error or not.

Comment: I just had to add my ```let response = insertOffice(i); ...``` above the ```throw Error('unexpected Error') ```  and worked, thank you mate :)

Comment: I used your second example

Comment: @MartínJF 
Cool Good For You :))  Good Luck

Comment: Lol, I figured out it is because of the ```throw Error('unexpected Error')``` right? When I comment that line I get the same issue, success message is shown, any idea why?

Comment: so simple bro your code doesnt throw any error in fail situation 
try to use if statement , if (success condition) { log(success) } else { log(error) }

Comment: @MartínJF if your code doesnt throws any error it cant be catched with try and catch . Good Luck

Comment: Thank you mate, let my try what you said :)